# Parse tableView can't change Label in Custom Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, parse-platform

Why is it not possible to change the Label.text of the following objects? (timeLabel, tweetOnTimelineTextfield, autorlabel)?

If I want to change values of these objects ("cell.timeLabel", "cell.autorlabel") it doesn't work!

I created a Class called TimelineTableViewCell (for my Custom Cell) and linked it in storyboard.

The main code of the PFQueryTableViewController is in the TimelineTableViewController.

Here is the code:

TimelineTableViewCell.h:

```
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

  @interface TimelineTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

  @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timeLabel;
  @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *tweetOnTimelineTextfield;
  @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *autorLabel;

  @end
```

TimeLineViewController.m:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
TimelineTableViewCell *cell = (TimelineTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (!cell)
{
    cell = [[TimelineTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}


NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, MMMM d yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [object createdAt];

// Configure the cell

cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"content"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Priority: %@", [object objectForKey:@"createdAt"]];

return cell;
}
```

TimeLineViewController.h:

```
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
  #import <Parse/Parse.h>
  @interface TimelineTableViewController : PFQueryTableViewController
  @end
```

Comment: Where do you try to set the text of those labels? In the code you show, you're only setting the default labels of a UITableViewCell.

Comment: I tried to set the code in the TimelineTablewViewController with cell.

Comment: But you never do cell.timeLabel = ... or cell.autorLabel = ..., so how would you expect it to change those labels?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, now it works! The intellisens didn't show me the labels of the other class(if I tried cell.a -> the only propose was cell.auto(?!). However now I tried cell.autorLabel.text and it works perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Go to your TimelineTableViewCell.m file and synthesize the properties of the custom cell.

So you'll have this

```
@implementation TimelineTableViewCell
@synthesize timeLabel,tweetOnTimelineTextfield,autorLabel;
```

You should be good to go!

Enjoy!

Comment: Really? You don't need to use @synthesize any more, and in any case, that has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: @rdelmar Ofcourse his problem will be solved if he has his properties synthesized and he sets them from where he creates his cell. So he'll have cell.timeLabel.text=@"bla bla bla" , cell.tweetOnTimelineTextfield.text=@"bla bla bla" and cell.autorLabel.text=@"bla bla bla"

Comment: No, they won't be solved. There's no need to synthesize properties any more, since they're now auto-synthesized. You haven't needed to do that since the LLVM compiler 4.0 was introduced in Xcode 4.